# How to calculate mean of columns if not all columns are present in all the files?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have multiple text files, containing various columns. I want the mean only for a few columns that may or may not exist in each group of files.

I am using following code to calculate the mean of the selected columns. I am facing the issue where not all the files have all the columns. For example, files in folder 1 have all of the columns, files in folder 2 have columns C1, C2, C8, C9 and files in folder 3 have columns col C1, C2, C5, etc.

Because of this reason, it is generating output only for Folder 1 which have all the columns and giving an error for Folder 2 and 3 that columns (which are not present in respective folder) are not found.

I want that code should run in a way that if a file contains any column(s) from the selected columns in cn, its mean should be calculated in the output, without giving any error that other columns mentioned in cn is not present in the file.

Code:

```
merged <- rbindlist(dt.tidied, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)

cn <- c('Date/Time', 'C1 (C1)', 'C2 (C2)', 'C5 (C5)', 'C8 (C8)', 'C9 (C9)', 'C10 (C10)')

abc <- merged[, ..cn] %>%
 as_tibble() %>%
 group_by(Time_sp = lubridate::floor_date(`Date/Time`, "5 mins")) %>% 
 summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.5) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = 
                                                                               TRUE)))

write.csv(abc, paste0(dirlist[idx],"_mean.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: We can use `any_of()` with `select`.

Comment: `merged[, .SD, .SDcols=intersect(names(merged), cn)]` or `merged[, intersect(names(merged), cn), with=FALSE]`

Comment: Consider avoiding mixing R flavors in your processing semantics such as data.table and dplyr. For maintenance, chose one and stick with it. The former can run grouped aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
merged <- rbindlist(dt.tidied, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)

cn <- c('Date/Time', 'C1 (C1)', 'C2 (C2)', 'C5 (C5)', 'C8 (C8)', 'C9 (C9)', 'C10 (C10)')

merged %>%
 select(any_of(cn)) %>%
 as_tibble() %>%
 group_by(Time_sp = lubridate::floor_date(`Date/Time`, "5 mins")) %>% 
 summarise(across(where(is.numeric),
           ~ ifelse(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.5), NA, mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE ))) -> abc

write.csv(abc, paste0(dirlist[idx],"_mean.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
```